# Access to a parent set/get method from one object inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, json

I have an object "parent" that have one setter/getter method "a", and this object have also an array of objects "let's call it array" created with a Object Constructor, the think is that with the object inside the "array" I want to access to the method a.

I put some code for better undestanding:

```
function parent()
{
   this.a; //This is a setter/getter method
   this.array=[]; // array of objects
   this.array.push(new child());
}

function child()
{
   this.aParentMehod;
}

b=new parent();
```

what I want is that `b.array[0].aParentMethod` returns `b.a`,

By the way, I'm using object Constructors because i dont know how many childs I will have, but It here is a better method to do the same, please tell me.

Thank you in advance

Edit:

I have achived by doing this:

```
function parent()
{
   this.a; //This is a setter/getter method
   this.array=[]; // array of objects
   this.array.push(new child(self));
}

function child(self)
{
   this.parent=self;
   this.aParentMehod=this.parent.a;
}

b=new parent();
```

But when I change the Parent `a` propety, the child porpety dosen't change and `aParentMehod` shows the inicial propety of `a`

Comment: I've tried to answer the question, but it's not very clear, esp. as the code given is clearly pseudo-code...

Comment: Yes It's pseudocode cause all the code is very large, the idea is that i have an undeterminated number of childs that will be cvreated when I load a file, and all this childs have to access to a setter/getter method in the parents object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what I want is that `b.array[0].aParentMethod` returns `b.a`,

You'll need to do two things to make that happen:

1. Pass the parent object reference into the child
2. Add a getter to the child that uses the parent reference to get `a`

E.g., something like this (see `***` comments):

```
function parent()
{
   this.a;
   this.array=[];
   this.array.push(new child(this));                      // ***
}

function child(parent)                                    // ***
{
   this.parent = parent;
}
Object.defineProperty(child.prototype, "aParentMethod", { // ***
    get: function() {                                     // ***
        return this.parent.a;                             // ***
    }                                                     // ***
});                                                       // ***

b=new parent();
```

This isn't an ideal structure, though; ideally you'd avoid having the child reference the parent (which would pretty much mean it couldn't have `aParentMethod`).

---

Side note: The overwhelming convention in JavaScript is that constructor functions like yours are written with an initial capital letter. So `Parent` and `Child` rather than `parent` and `child`. Conventions like that aid readability.

Comment: Thank you a lot. so for example, If i have 10 Childs objects in the array, and all this childs needs to access to a setter/getter method from the parent how I have to code this?

Thank you a lot again, I'm starting coding and all this Conventions/Tricks are very usefull for me.

Comment: @david.t_92: You'd just repeat the first `***` line above for all ten children.